# Calogero-Moser eigenfunction

Tags: differential-equations, computer-algebra, integrable-systems

The folllowing function
\begin{equation}
J(t_1,t_2,t_3,m,h)=[(1-e^{t_1-t_2})(1-e^{t_2-t_3})(1-e^{t_1-t_3})]^{-m/h} e^{-\frac{a_1t_1+a_2t_2+a_3t_3}{h}}\sum_{k_{1,1},k_{2,1},k_{2,2}\ge0}e^{(t_1-t_2)k_{1,1}+(t_2-t_3)(k_{2,1}+k_{2,2})}\prod_{i=1}^2\prod_{j=1}^2\frac{(1-\frac{a_i}{h}+\frac{a_j}{h}+\frac{m}{h})_{k_{2,i}-k_{2,j}}}{(-\frac{a_i}{h}+\frac{a_j}{h})_{k_{2,i}-k_{2,j}}}\prod_{i=1}^2\frac{(-\frac{a_1}{h}+\frac{a_i}{h}-\frac{m}{h})_{k_{1,1}-k_{2,i}}}{(1-\frac{a_1}{h}+\frac{a_i}{h})_{k_{1,1}-k_{2,i}}} \prod_{i=1}^2\prod_{j=1}^3\frac{(-\frac{a_i}{h}+\frac{a_j}{h}-\frac{m}{h})_{k_{2,i}}}{(1-\frac{a_i}{h}+\frac{a_j}{h})_{k_{2,i}}}
\end{equation} 
is supposed to be an eigenvalue of the Calogero-Moser Hamiltonian
\begin{equation}
H=\sum_{i=1}^3\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t_i^2}-2\frac{m}{h}(\frac{m}{h}+1)\Bigg[\frac{e^{t_1-t_2}}{(1-e^{t_1-t_2})^2}+\frac{e^{t_2-t_3}}{(1-e^{t_2-t_3})^2}+\frac{e^{t_1-t_3}}{(1-e^{t_1-t_3})^2} \Bigg]
\end{equation} 
with an eigenvalue
\begin{equation}
HJ=\Bigg[\frac{a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2}{h^2}\Bigg]J
\end{equation} 
Note that we use the Pochhammer symbol $(x)_k$ defined by
\begin{equation}
(x)_k = \left\{ 
\begin{array}{cc}
\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} (x+i) & \,\,\text{for}\,\, k>0\\
1 & \,\,\text{for}\,\, k=0\\
\prod_{i=1}^{k} \dfrac{1}{x-i} & \,\,\text{for}\,\, k<0
\end{array}
\right. 
\end{equation}
I would like hopefully to prove, or at least to check that the function $J$ is an eigenfunction of the Calogero-Moser Hamiltonian $H$ for some powers of $e^{t_i}$. However, the expression is too complicated so that I don't even know how I can check it by Mathematica. From [this link](http://goo.gl/pm6S8p), you can download a file including the expression of the function $J$. I wonder if somebody could tell me a good way to prove or to check the equation.

PS) I also posted the same question to [mathematica stackexchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55267/checking-calogero-moser-eigenfunction) since I thought an expert in Mathematica may be able to help me.

Here's the function $J$; paste this in to Mathematica:

```
J[t1_,t2_,t3_,h_,m_,p_,q_,r_]:=((1-E^(t1-t2))(1-E^(t2-t3))(1-E^(t1-t3)))^(-m/h)E^(-(Subscript[a, 1]t1+Subscript[a, 2]t2+Subscript[a, 3]t3)/(h))Sum[E^((t1-t2)(Subscript[k, 1,1])+(t2-t3)(Subscript[k, 2,1]+Subscript[k, 2,2]))(\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Product]\), \(j = 1\), \(2\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Product]\), \(i = 1\), \(2\)]
\*FractionBox[\(Pochhammer[\(-
\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(i\)]\)/h + 
\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(j\)]/h + m/h + 1, 
\*SubscriptBox[\(k\), \(2, i\)] - 
\*SubscriptBox[\(k\), \(2, j\)]]\), \(Pochhammer[\(-
\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(i\)]\)/h + 
\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(j\)]/h, 
\*SubscriptBox[\(k\), \(2, i\)] - 
\*SubscriptBox[\(k\), \(2, j\)]]\)]\)\))(\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Product]\), \(j = 1\), \(2\)]
\*FractionBox[\(Pochhammer[\(-
\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(1\)]\)/h + 
\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(j\)]/h - m/h, 
\*SubscriptBox[\(k\), \(1, 1\)] - 
\*SubscriptBox[\(k\), \(2, j\)]]\), \(Pochhammer[1 - 
\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(1\)]/h + 
\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(j\)]/h, 
\*SubscriptBox[\(k\), \(1, 1\)] - 
\*SubscriptBox[\(k\), \(2, j\)]]\)]\))(\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Product]\), \(ell = 1\), \(3\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Product]\), \(i = 1\), \(2\)]
\*FractionBox[\(Pochhammer[\(-
\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(i\)]\)/h + 
\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(ell\)]/h - m/h, 
\*SubscriptBox[\(k\), \(2, i\)]]\), \(Pochhammer[1 - 
\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(i\)]/h + 
\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(ell\)]/h, 
\*SubscriptBox[\(k\), \(2, i\)]]\)]\)\)),{Subscript[k, 1,1],0,p},{Subscript[k, 2,1],0,q},{Subscript[k, 2,2],0,r}]
```